Bind9: can support forward but modify domain name?
For example:
I want

domain a.b.region1.example.net forward to 10.0.0.1 and change domain name to a.b.example.com
domain a.b.region2.example.net forward to 10.0.1.1 and change domain name to a.b.example.com

Reason:
I use a cloud provider volcengine.com. They provide internal DNS with zone ivolces.com. But this domain can have different zone file in different region.
I want to resolve in in my datacenter, but the domain is not unique.
So I want to use my domain append region and then forword to different volce's region DNS server.

DNS can't change names. It can point to different names (cname), but not change the name the client uses.

I agree with vidarlo. If it is for web purpose you could setup a "mini"-website whose only purpose is to do a header redirect to the wanted domain. It is easily done with Apache or PHP or DotNet or ...

@vidarlo: Since OP mentioned 'forward' I assume they're talking about DNS server configuration, not plain zone files, and in theory a DNS server could change names as it forwards the request – more or less how the "ALIAS" pseudo rrtype is often implemented – or do anything else it wants, really...
